# how I can change the color of the TextView while the user is typing the text in the EditText

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

Please tell me how I can change the color of the `TextView` while the user is typing the text in the `EditText` in the same fragment. Here is some of the code from my fragment.

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
     TextView  text1 = v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     EditText text2 = v.findViewById(R.id.EditText2);
     if (text2.hasFocus()) {text1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);} else text1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
     return v;
    }
```

Comment: You have to use a listener.

Comment: If you want to change color only based on whether the user is typing or not you can use above mentioned method of setting the `onFocusChangeListener`, otherwise if you want to have a different colors based on the actual input you should add `addTextChangedListener(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `if (text2.hasFocus())` is executed only once and when the user is not typing in the `EditText`.

You have to use a listener to do that.
For example:

```
    EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textview);

    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.xxxx));
            } else {
                textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.xxx));
            }
        }
    });
```

[image]
[image]